# PHP preg_replace multiple url replaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Hey I am trying to do 2 preg_replace:
1.make all urls to html links
2.make all images url to html img tag

But these regexs cancel the other one

```
<?php
// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
$reg_exImg = "!http://[a-z0-9\-\.\/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.comhttp://www.ynet.co.il http://dogsm.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/d7a1d7a7d795d791d799-d793d795.jpg";

// Check if there is a url in the text
    $text = preg_replace($reg_exImg, '<img src=$0 >', $text);
    $text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$0" rel="nofollow">$0</a>', $text);
    echo $text;
?>
```

How can I make that the preg_replace that make url to links dont do this to the  tag?

Thanks.

Haim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better as a callback.

Use just the `$reg_exUrl`, and do this:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback($reg_exUrl,function($m) {
    if( preg_match("/\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$/i",$m[0])) {
        return "<img src='".$m[0]."' />";
    }
    else {
        return "<a href='".$m[0]."' rel='nofollow'>".$m[0]."</a>";
    }
},$text);
```